# Creating a table with avg using a join

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to create a table in which I can acquire an average and then group these averages by name. This is the current SQL I have written and it doesn't seem to be working. The error I am getting is

> SQL Error: ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis

Here is the SQL below. Can anyone help? Thanks

```
CREATE TABLE new_table_name AS
(Select distinct table_name1.column_name1, AVG(table_name2.column_name2)
FROM  table_name1, table_name2
WHERE table_name1.table_id1 = table_name2.table_id2 
group by table_name1.column_name1
order BY table_name1.column_name1);
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
create table new_table_name as
select t1.column_name1,
    AVG(t2.column_name2) column_name2
from table_name1 t1
join table_name2 t2 on t1.table_id1 = t2.table_id2
group by t1.column_name1;
```

Changes made:

- Use column alias for the `AVG(t2.column_name2)`
- `DISTINCT` not needed as you are doing `group by`
- use explicit modern join syntax instead of older comma based join
- Order by is not required and also, is the real cause of error because a table in RDBMS is a unordered set of rows .
- Use aliases to cleanup

Comment: If I wanted to add another table to the SQL could I just add another row like this "join table_name2 t2 on t1.table_id1 = t2.table_id2"